# Loading external javascript in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension which manipulates the current page (basically adds a button).

In my content script, I want to load the Facebook Graph API:

```
$fbDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'fb-root');
$fbScript = $(document.createElement('script')).attr('src', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');
$(body).append($fbDiv);
$(body).append($fbScript);

console.log("fbScript: " + typeof $fbScript.get(0));
console.log("fbScript parent: " + typeof $fbScript.parent().get(0));
console.log("find through body: " + typeof $(body).find($fbScript.get(0)).get(0));
```

However, the script doesn't seem to added to `body`. Here's the console log:

```
fbScript: object
fbScript parent: undefined
find through body: undefined
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just include the Facebook JS as one of your content scripts?

Comment: I tried that but I'm not able to even load the script in the extension window. It comes up with this error: Could not load extension from '/Users/.../extentionfolder/'. Could not load javascript 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js' for content script.

Comment: That's because you're providing an external reference, but Chrome expects the script to be local. I'm not too familiar with the Facebook Graph API; how feasible is it to save a local copy with your extension?

Comment: Check my answer for using aws-sdk in chrome extensions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893562/chrome-extension-which-uses-aws-services/58598444#58598444

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The issue is that the JavaScript inside the content scripts runs in its own sandboxed environment and only has access to other JavaScript that was loaded in one of two ways:

Via the [manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration):

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Or using [Programmatic injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi):

```
/* in background.html */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                       {file:"https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"});
});
```

Be sure to update your manifest permissions:

```
/* in manifest.json */
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://connect.facebook.net"
 ],
```

Appending a script tag will in effect evaluate the JavaScript in the context of the containing page, outside of the JavaScript sandbox that your JavaScript has access to.

Also, since the FB script requires the "fb-root" to be in the DOM, you will probably need to use the programmatic approach so that you can first update the DOM with the element, then [pass a message](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) back to the background page to load the Facebook script so it is accessible to the JavaScript that is loaded in the content scripts.

Comment: hi, i was under impression that you need to do this or something... http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
....but would this work to. Now. 2013.

Comment: This is no longer correct as per https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading

Comment: this loads a script on the content page, but I am looking to load a script in the extension

Answer (score 13):

Google Chrome extensions no longer allow injecting external code directly, however you can still download the code with an Ajax call and feed it to the injector as if it was a code block.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/plugin/somesite.js", function(result) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: result});
    }, "text");
});
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645710/720665

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load it as content script:

```js
fetch('https://example.com/content.js')
  .then(resp => resp.text())
  .then(eval)
  .catch(console.error)
```

If you want to load it as background script.
Take https://example.com/bg.js for example.

1. add the remote js script to the background page file, which is named background.html here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://example.com/bg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Empty content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. add **https://example.com** to the content_security_policy of the manifest.json:

```json
"background": {
  "page": "background.html"
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com ; object-src 'self'",
```

Requirements:

1. The remote js script must be served via **https** instead of http.
2. You should specify a **page** rather than a scripts array in the background section