# Chrome Countdown Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have modified [this](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/) countdown script to countdown to 4:20pm everyday. I have attempted to create a Google Chrome app that displays the countdown. The javascript is supposed replace a paragraph tag with id of "note" with the time left. It works when I load the page in chrome, but does not work when I load the extension. Example, if I put:

```
<p id="note">asdf</a>
```

I get just the text, "asdf", but when I open the html file I get the countdown.

Here is the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Here is the popup.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>4:20PM Countdown</title>

    <!-- Our CSS stylesheet file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://treesmoke.com/cd/assets/css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://treesmoke.com/cd/assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <p id="note">asdf</p>
    <!-- JavaScript includes -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://treesmoke.com/cd/assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://treesmoke.com/cd/assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's](http://treesmoke.com/cd/popup.html) the popup.html page, showing that the script works.

Thanks guys, it isn't that big of a deal if I can't get it to work. I was just bored and decided to learn a little.

Edit: The main problem with my page was that I tried to load javascript and css from the internet when I had to do it locally. Now it works.

Comment: What is inside your script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781851/loading-external-javascript-in-google-chrome-extension) that explains the external js loading in extensions.
It should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this is my problem.