# is it possible to execute functions of background page on chrome tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that needs to execute some functions on each tabs it works on, but [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) in HTML5 prevents the extension to append needed scripts to some websites like [pinterest](http://www.pinterest.com/). because of update issues, I load this script from my website, How could I load the script from source "http://mywebsite.com/loader-script.js" and execute it on each tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading external scripts is only possible through two ways:
[Loading external javascript in google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781851/loading-external-javascript-in-google-chrome-extension)

This will answer you question.
Regards, Benedikt

Comment: Thank you. yes, I executed the file instead of appending it, it was a little tricky but solved