# Chrome extension: load and execute external script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, external-script

I have trouble loading and executing external js-script into my chrome extension. Looks the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781851/loading-external-javascript-in-google-chrome-extension), but I still cant't figure out why it doesn't work in my case.

The idea is that I want to have in my content script some default function which should parse a web-page content. And for some specific web-pages I want to load and use specific parsers, so I try to load proper js-script for a wep-page, and this script shoud extend functionality of default parser.

By now I try only execute code from external script, but have such error: `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: No source code or file specified at Object.callback`

This is my **manifest.json**:

```
{
"name": "Extension name",
"version": "1.2",
"description": "My chrome extension",
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "css": [
        "style.css"
    ],
    "js": [
        "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "content.js"
    ],
    "matches": ["*://*/*"]
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "frame.html",
    "logo-48.png"
],
"icons": {
    "16": "logo-16.png",
    "48": "logo-48.png",
    "128": "logo-128.png"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
],
"manifest_version": 2
```

}

This is **popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <li>Some link</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

And in **popup.js** i execute scrip like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/plugin/somesite.js"});
});
```

What am I dong wrong, did I miss something? Or should I use another approach to solve the issue?

Comment: Remark (not connected with your error): `"http://*/"` matches ONLY top level pages. You may want either `"<all_urls>"` for a broad permission or `"activeTab"` if you only need access to the current tab.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't have `somesite.js` loaded into your extension?

Comment: To catch lastError, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880/632951

Answer (score 10):

Running scripts from external sources like you try is forbidden by google chrome and will block or even not publish your extension. All scripts must be in the extension. But there is a solution,
[from google chrome doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy):

> The restriction against resources loaded over HTTP applies only to
>   those resources which are directly executed. You're still free, for
>   example, to make XMLHTTPRequest connections to any origin you like;
>   the default policy doesn't restrict connect-src or any of the other
>   CSP directives in any way.

If you need badly an external source, you can do a XML HTTP request and use the eval to the content. Here is a part of code [from google doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#security-considerations):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/plugin/somesite.js", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      // WARNING! Might be evaluating an evil script!
      var resp = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      // Or this if it's work
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: xhr.responseText});
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

or you can use some library, [$.get() with jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [$http with angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).
if you add eval in your code you must add in manifest.json this:

```
"content_security_policy":  "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`,
```

Comment: This is not true. See the official chrome extension tutorial which load google analytics via script tag: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics

Answer (score 5):

As per the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/LIH7LGXeQHo,

> Running scripts from external sources may cause your extension to be unpublished or blocked.

Just providing another approach, you could make an ajax call to the content script then call `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/plugin/somesite.js", function(result) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: result});
    }, "text");
});
```

Comment: Can't downloading and executing a script be considered as `Running scripts from external sources`? Is it allowed by Google?

Answer (score 2):

The 'file' option for executeScript only relates to **files** embedded in your extension. I know, [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) isn't clear on that and while it might work with URLs, it sounds like a hack, not a feature. In order to load scripts from external sources into your active page, you usually have to execute a script that creates a script tag inside the DOM of the loaded document there.

I feel I have answered parts of this question before here: [Why is chrome.tabs.executeScript() necessary to change the current website DOM and how can I use jQuery to achieve the same effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385012/why-is-chrome-tabs-executescript-necessary-to-change-the-current-website-dom-a/36385098#36385098)

To summarize:

1) in order to have access to web pages from the extension, you need to add [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for it:

```
"permissions" : [
       "tabs",
       [...]
       "http://*/*",
       "https://*/*" ],
```

2) you need to execute some sort of code that creates the DOM script element that loads what you need:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code : 'var script=document.createElement(\'script\');' +
    'script.onload=function() { /*do something in the page after the script was loaded*/ };' +
    'script.src=\'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/plugin/somesite.js\';' +
    'document.body.appendChild(script);'
}, function (returnedValue) {
    // do something in the extension context after the code was executed
});
```

Take a look at the `remex` function in the link above, which I think solves a lot of the ugliness of javascript written as a string as here.

Comment: But this won't run as extension code. It will run as the page's JavaScript.