# chrome extension which uses AWS services

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-chrome-extension

I'm setting up a new chrome extension that suppose to allow/block certain file download. I need to send urls to AWS lambda, process the file and return a boolean back.

I already implemented the chrome extension part that listen to new downloads, pause them and extract the URL. I can't figure out how to send this URL to an AWS lambda service to process. I can't create an AWS object in order to use its services because I use JS on client side and not NodeJS.

```
import { S3, Lambda } from 'aws-sdk';

var s3 = new S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
```

First line throws error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I expected it to compile as the vscode fixed me after I wrote NodeJS syntax:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

How can I use AWS services from javascript chrome extension then?

Comment: If you set up the lambda as a HTTP endpoint you can just treat it like a REST API and you don't need to try to interact directly with AWS (which you definitely don't want to be trying to do from a Chrome extension for various reasons).

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the quick reply.
I need to send a url to AWS Lambda from my extension and then send back a boolean, the only issue is that I can't figure out how they talk to each other.

Do I need to install aws-sdk locally?